# Can I restart Godus from the beginning?

Tags: godus

Is there a way that I can reset the game so that I can start from the beginning?

I was thinking about deleting the local content and restarting but am slightly worried that if this is synced to steam cloud that it will just reload everything like it is at the moment.

[Note] This has now been fixed in the latest version of the godus beta

Answer (score 2):

I moved the local content I had at `~/Library/Application Support/godus` (on osx, this is not the steam apps folder even though steam installed it) and successfully restarted the game from the beginning.

Comment: That makes sense. "Application Support" is (approximately) the Mac equivalent of "My Games" on Windows, which Steam-based games typically use for save data.

Comment: I will have to have a look to see if that method may work on my PC version of the game